# How to install keras module in python 2 environment conda?

Tags: python, anaconda, keras

I've already installed keras. It works in python 3 using spyder in conda. But when I run in python 2 (which is installed in an environment), it has an error 
`ImportError: No module named keras.layers.core` and when I try to install keras by using command prompt it said that I've already installed.

Comment: You tried to install Keras by using command promt in which environment? The python2 one or python3 one?

Comment: I don't know how to see the python version when i install. could you give me a way?  FalconUA

Comment: `python --version` to see the version of python, `pip --version` to see version of pip installer.

Comment: it's 3.6. How to change it to be 2

Comment: Try `conda info --envs` to see the list of created environments. Then, move to the environment with python2 by `source activate your_py2_environment` or `activate your_py2_environment`. Then, check your python and pip again. Note that environments are *self-contained*, so if you have installed Keras in one environment, you can't use it in another environment. [Here](https://conda.io/docs/using/envs.html) is how to manage environments. [Here](https://conda.io/docs/py2or3.html) is how to manage python versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To simplify the management of different environments in the same machine I use Conda.
Create a new conda environment and specify the python version

```
conda create --name your_env_name python=2.7
```

Then activate the environment with

```
activate your_env_name
```

or

```
source activate your_env_name
```

Now you can install keras in a new environment with

```
pip install keras
```

Comment: i try to activate environment but the error occur C:\Users\Administrator>activate your_env_name
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: can't initialize sys standard streams
LookupError: unknown encoding: 874

Current thread 0x00000c2c (most recent call first):
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: can't initialize sys standard streams
LookupError: unknown encoding: 874

Current thread 0x0000106c (most recent call first):
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: can't initialize sys standard streams
LookupError: unknown encoding: 874

Current thread 0x000005ac (most recent call first):

Comment: Check if the environment has been created, type
`conda env list`